# Modify site title link URL

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, master-page

Is it possible to modify the v4.master in SharePoint 2010 Designer to another URL as "~site"?
I wanna change the titel link URL to my Homepage URL.
Here is the code from the v4.master page:

```
 <td class="s4-titletext">
  <h1 name="onetidProjectPropertyTitle">
      <SharePoint:SPLinkButton runat="server" NavigateUrl="~site/" 
         id="onetidProjectPropertyTitle"><SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" 
         runat="server" /></SharePoint:SPLinkButton>
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
  </h1>
```

If it's not possible to change the URL by using the SharePoint Designer, is it possible with some code (javascript)?

Comment: I dind't understand your question. Do you need to change the title of your URL or modify the Navigation URL? These are different things. Can you explain better please?

Comment: Sorry for being so complicated. I wanna change the  Navigation URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the property `NavigateUrl`, change `~site` to `~sitecollection` for it to always link to your homepage URL.

Comment: I tried and saved your solution, but nothing happened. If i click on the Site title it doesn't "jump" to my Homepage.
I don't know why it won't work.

Comment: @Tiac Does your `NavigateUrl` property look like this `NavigateUrl="~sitecollection/"`?

Comment: Yes. After showing up your solution i changed my code into that:
NavigateUrl="~sitecollection/"

Comment: Do i have to change the URL only in v4.master or do i have to change it  in minimal.master or default.master?
I don't know the differences of this page, so i only changed the v4.master.

Comment: @Tiac You have to make this change in the Masterpage you use as your main masterpage.

Comment: Sorry but now i'm very confused. Do you speak from the main masterpage of my subsite? So this must be one of the 3 pages (v4.master,minmal.master or deafutl.master). Or do you mean that i have to change the masterpage of my root site. I'm very sorry but i don't get it..